# Encountering type mismatch error (13) when passing a parameter to a function

Tags: excel, vba

I received type mismatch(13) error when I tried to run the sub.
It seems to be about the parameter j I pass to function DivisionCase. I don't understand why, please enlighten me.
Second thought: Do I need to pass j byref?

```
    Function Last_Row(column)
    'Find the last Row with data in a column
        With ActiveSheet
            Last_Row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).Row
        End With
    End Function

    Sub verticalProfileCalc()
    Dim currentParaBVC As Variant: currentParaBVC = Null
    Dim j As Long
    Dim value1 As Variant
    Dim value2 As Variant
    
    For j = 2 To Last_Row(11)
    
    value1 = CDec(Cells(j, 12).Value)
    value2 = CDec(Cells(j, 13).Value)
    Cells(j, 16).Value = CDec(DivisionCase(value1, value2, j, currentParaBVC))
    Next j
    End Sub

    Function DivisionCase(ByVal downchain As Variant, ByVal upchain As Variant, ByVal currentRow As Long, ByRef currentParaBVC As Variant) As Variant
    
    Dim downchainSection As Integer: downchainSection = Cells(currentRow, 14).Value
    Dim upchainSection As Integer: upchainSection = Cells(currentRow, 15).Value
    Dim verticalProfile As Variant: verticalProfile = CDec(Cells(currentRow, 16).Value)
    Dim LineType As String: LineType = Application.VLookup(downchainSection, "CurveSchedule", 4, False)
    Dim Grade As Variant
    Dim ParabolicLength As Variant: ParabolicLength = CDec(Application.VLookup(downchainSection, "CurveSchedule", 3, False) - Application.VLookup(downchainSection, "CurveSchedule", 2, False))
        If currentRow = 2 Then
        verticalProfile = CDec(Range("InitialPoint").Value)
        'temporarily assignd initvalue to cell P2
        ElseIf downchainSection = upchainSection Then
            
                If LineType = "Straight" Then
                    'do something
                    
                ElseIf LineType = "Parabolic" Then
                   'do something
                End If
                
            ElseIf ((upchainSection - downchainSection) = 1) Then
                
                If LineType = "Straight" Then
                    'do something                          
                ElseIf LineType = "Parabolic" Then
                    'do something
                End If
                
            End If
        DivisionCase = CDec(verticalProfile)
    End Function
```

Comment: Could you share the code of the last procedure? At first glance, the last procedure should be a `sub` and the last parameter should be `ByRef`, while the first three should be `ByVal`. It looks unusual, so there is a probability that the last procedure should be rewritten as a function. Not sure, without seeing its code and understanding its purpose. Also, you should change `As Integer` to `As Long`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 . I've posted more of the code. Essentially, the function DivisionCase is meant to take decimal inputs (downchain, upchain and currentParaBVC) and return a decimal result (verticalProfile). It seems that in the sub verticalProfileCalc, the line where I assign the value of cells(j,16) to the return value of the function DivisionCase is the problem.

Comment: At which row do you get the error? Could you post a screenshot of the data - with column and row-headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## One possible solution

I gave your code a shot with some made up data on my end, and here's what I see.  This line:

```
Dim LineType As String: LineType = Application.VLookup(downchainSection, "CurveSchedule", 4, False)
```

It fails on a Type 13 Mismatch because it should be:

```
Dim LineType As String: LineType = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(downchainSection, "CurveSchedule", 4, False)
```

You have the object reference wrong; you need the `WorksheetFunction`.  That's probably not your only problem, though...

### Other possible issues to check

Just fixing the above didn't work, though. I don't know what "CurveSchedule" is referring to -- presumably a named range or a list object table?.  Either way, VBA is reading that as a string as written.  If it's a named range, I got it to work with `ActiveSheet.Range("CurveSchedule")`. So the line that works for me looks like this:

```
Dim LineType As String: LineType = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(downchainSection, Range("CurveSchedule"), 4, False)
```

Also, because I'm making up my own data, I had an issue with the var `downchainSection` because I didn't have any value in that cell when it was assigned.  Presumably, you do, so probably not an issue for you.

I don't know if that's your issue or not, but if this doesn't help you, I strongly recommend stepping through with F8 (on Windows, anyway) and tell us exactly what line of code it's failing on. Once I find the line that the code is failing, I start changing the line to simpler things (because I tend to write complex thinking I'm better than I am) until I find the line working, then work my way back to complex seeing what works.

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` and `Application.VLookup` are both correct; the former is early-bound and *raises* VBA run-time errors on fail, the latter is late-bound and *returns* a worksheet error on fail. Both behaviors have their uses, but indeed early-bound code is preferable in most cases. Since the late-bound version *returns* a `Variant/Error` value that cannot be implicitly or explicitly converted to any other data type, the type mismatch is most likely caused by the VLOOKUP function failing its lookup and then the `#N/A` worksheet error being assigned to a `String`.

Comment: I am familiar with early and late binding, but only in the context of whether or not to use `CreateObject()` or set references in Tools.  I'll need to read up more on this, but appreciate the comment @MathieuGuindon.

Comment: `CreateObject` only creates an object instance off a registry key, it doesn't necessarily involve late binding! What makes a call late-bound (resolved at run-time) is when that call is made against `Object` or `Variant`. When the class type is known to the compiler, it's declared `As TheClassName`, and that's only possible when the library that defines `TheClassName` is referenced - which makes the `New` operator much more convenient than `CreateObject` ;-)

Comment: In this particular case the `Application` object is being extended at run-time with what appears to be an implementation of the `WorksheetFunction` interface; extended members only exist at run-time by definition, making them all late-bound calls.